# NodeJS wait for API response

Tags: node.js

### Intro

Greetings, im developing a simple NodeJS application for fun and a critical feature i need is to shorten URLs with goo.gl.

I found a package which works fine and im really happy with it, however i need to expose the result (shortened url) as json back to the user.

### Problem

The problem is that once i call the short function it doesn't return the link because it doesn't wait for it to finish the request, instead it continues.

### Code

```
var googl = require('goo.gl')

module.exports = {
googl: function(link) {
    
    if (!process.env.GOOGLKEY) {
        return JSON.stringify({
            status: false,
            message: 'No API Key set for goo.gl'
        })
    };

    googl.setKey(process.env.GOOGLKEY)

    googl.shorten(link).then(function(url) {
        return {
            message: url
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })

    

}
}
```

As you can see `googl.shorten(link).then()` does not return anything.

If i try to do something like `var resp = googl.shorten(link).then()` and then return `resp` all i get is `pending`.

What i need to do is to wait untill goo.gl responds back.
Any ides how to do it?

Comment: In node.js you shouldn't wait. What you need to do is pass the code you want to execute once the result is completed to then()

Comment: I just want to return the value. what should i do?

Comment: You can't. Read up on Promises and/or Callbacks to solve your problem.

Comment: How can i implement a promise on the code above?

Answer (score 0):

```
var googl = require('goo.gl')

module.exports = {
    googl: function(link, callback) {

        if (!process.env.GOOGLKEY) {
            return JSON.stringify({
                status: false,
                message: 'No API Key set for goo.gl'
            })
        };

        googl.setKey(process.env.GOOGLKEY)

        googl.shorten(link).then(function(url) {
            callback.call(url); //this is the function that you pass as an argument and is executed when you google answers
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
};
```

In order to use it, you can do so like this

```
googl('URL_TO_TRANSFORM_HERE', function(url) { //By the way, this is your googl function, not the other that you require.
    console.log('Retrievend asynchronoysly this url : ' + url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a callback approach will work just fine, in this case I would suggest returning the promise because its already implemented using promises.

All you have to do is move the promise out of your module. e.g.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
// myshortener.js
var googl = require('goo.gl')

module.exports = {
    googl: function(link) {

    if (!process.env.GOOGLKEY) {
        return JSON.stringify({
            status: false,
            message: 'No API Key set for goo.gl'
        })
    };

    googl.setKey(process.env.GOOGLKEY)

    return googl.shorten(link)
       // ---------------------------------
       // MOVE .then() FROM MODULE HERE ...
       // ---------------------------------
}
```

move promise into client code as follows:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
// main.js
var shortener = require('myshortener')

shortener.googl(link)
   // ---------------------------------
   // ... TO CLIENT CODE HERE
   // ---------------------------------
       .then(function(url) {
           return {
               message: url
           }
       })
       .catch(function(err) {
           console.log(err)
       })
```

That way you are not mixing styles making the code more readable and maintainable.